# Can action parameter be a model in ASP.NET WEB API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an action where I am supposed to capture many primitive values including Enum types. I have created a model to match the required values.Can action parameter be a model in ASP.NET WEB API? Or I need to create a view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create a view model.
Models, view models, DTOs can all just be classes with properties on.
How each can or cannot be used is a decision you need to make.

Usually the main requirement from an API endpoint perspective is that the class into which the parameters are being deserialised has a default constructor. Then the parameters from the request will be assigned to properties of the equivalent name.